# matrix - using with channel fields

Tags: ee2, matrix, channel-form

I am creating a 'dashboard' for my users I use matrix to let them add their employment history.

They can update their profile via channel forms but

1 - how can I insert/add data into the matrix fields (examples if you have a link to one please.

1. is is possible to use the ajax style add row that I can when logged in as the superadmin in the EE backend?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Profile:Edit](http://mightybigrobot.com/products/detail/profile-edit) you can simply insert your custom channel field `{field:user_grid}` and it will automatically insert all the HTML and CSS/Javascript required for this module that would normally be inserted into the back end.